# Show that null solution is unstable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$ a $C^{1}$ function such that $f(0)=0$. Suppose that exist a non-null solution $\varphi$ of $x'=f(x)$ such that $\varphi(t)\to 0$ as $t\to -\infty.$ Show that null solution is unstable.

My attempt: Suppose, by absurd, the solution $\psi\equiv 0$ is stable. Thus, $\forall\varepsilon>0, \exists \delta >0$ such that $\forall x\in B_{\delta}(0)$ we have that trajectory by $x$ is defined for all $t\geq 0$ and $\|\varphi(t,x)\|<\varepsilon,\forall t\geq 0.$

That is, the solution $\varphi(t,x)$ stay in $B(\psi,\varepsilon),\forall \varepsilon>0.$

Thus, $\varphi(t)\to 0$ as $t\to+\infty.$ But, $\varphi\to 0$ as $t\to-\infty,$ this implies $\varphi \equiv 0$ and we have absurd.

Therefore, $\psi\equiv 0$ is unstable.

My solution is correct? I've doubts regarding the last steps.

Comment: With what argument do you conclude that it is the zero solution? You could use that there must be a maximum that can not exist, or that an autonomous $C^1$ DE has either constant or strictly monotonous solutions, or some other related property.

Comment: @LutzLehmann in this case, solution is $C^{1}.$ But I don't have any idea.